# 'Could not instantiate class named UITableViewCellContentView' iPhone 3.1.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've created a nib for a custom UITableView cell and followed the documentation and different tutorials to get past this error and it just won't let up. I researched this error and people say it's when you #import a header but you didn't add the Framework. Well, UIKit is automatically added, and I removed and added it again for good measure and this error won't let up. Here is my code for `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
     static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"PersonCell";

 PersonCell *cell = (PersonCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
 if(cell == nil)
 {
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PersonCell" owner:self options:nil];
  cell = personCell;
 }
        return cell;
```

Comment: What is a UITableViewCellContentView? That class is not in the SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution in dev forums

Create this files:

UITableViewCellContentView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UITableViewCellContentView : UIView {
}
```

UITableViewCellContentView.m

```
@implementation UITableViewCellContentView

+ (id)alloc {
    return [UIView alloc];
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [UIView allocWithZone:zone];
}

@end
```

Comment: UITableViewCellContentView as I understand can be private API... or no?

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, I had an app working in 3.1.2 for months and just downloaded the new 3.2 SDK for iPad, and my app ran fine in 3.2.  However, when I created my target in 3.1.2 (within the 3.2 SDK) and all the sudden had a null pointer in class UITableViewCellContentView (which I have never seen before). I am a novice at Obj C and could not figure out what what happening.  Found your entry by googling my error. I just reloaded the Original 3.1.2 SDK and the problem went away. Hope this helps.  Not sure if my code has a hidden error that is being triggered by the new SDK or there is something deeper going on.  I suspect it's my code, but it looks identical to your code in creating a custom cell for a table view.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem: after installing 3.2 beta, compiling to the 3.1.2 yielded this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the  UITableViewCellContentView' class worked for me in the simulator but I get an error on the phone when I run it.

*** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x51b9c of class 'UITableViewCellContentView' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort

I guess I'll have to reinstall the previous xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting the same error when running in 3.1.2 after installing the SDK 3.2 beta.  If I run my app in 3.2 (on the iPad simulator) it works fine.